# Django 1.8, Unable to run manage.py

Tags: python, django, manage.py

A newbie here. I am getting following erorr:

```
python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/app/models.py", line 61, in <module>
    }[connection.vendor]
KeyError: 'unknown'
```

Comment: Try running it after running this: `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi syncdb does not exist in newer versions of django, it's `migrate` now.

Comment: Before making migrate, you need to makemigrations first. And by the way, have you change the database setting in the settings.py file?

Comment: @shady No. I just cloned an app locally, the app using `postgres` which s not configured.

Comment: Refer this link for postgreSQL configuration [Use PostgreSQL with your Django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) @Volatil3

Answer (score 0):

If you look on the last line of the stack trace, you can see that you have an error in your `models.py` file on line 61.

`connection.vendor`, which you're using as a key, is `'unknown'`. That key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are presenting is a result of an improperly configured database.
Django does not know the type of database you are using and reports `unknown` which is not expected in the code

Please check your `DATABASES` configuration in your settings and make sure the right setting file is uses.

Answer (score 0):

Create and configure database before you migrate.

Please check your `settings.py` file

You may not have the correct `DATABASES` in your settings. There should be a database settings named `'default'`

Comment: it is using as `DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(env='DATABASE_URL')
    }`

and `DATABASE_URL` contains: `postgres://doc:doc@localhost/doc`

I am using Postgres Appp on OSX having `postgres` as a database and username